# LINQ exclude null while selecting into enumeration

Tags: c#, linq

The data below is just is sample data

```
ID  BatchName       File
===========================
1   Batch1          null 
2   Batch2          "C:\File2_1.pdf"
2   Batch2          "C:\File2_2.pdf"
3   Batch3          "C:\File3_1.pdf"
3   Batch3          "C:\File3_2.pdf"
```

Then i have a class that represents the above data

```
public class SourceBatch
{
   public int ID {get;set;}
   public string BatchName {get;set;}
   public string File {get;set;}
}
```

I want to group it by `ID` and `BatchName` and select all the `File` in that group into list. For that I have corresponding class

```
public class DestinationBatch
{
   public int ID {get;set;}
   public string BatchName {get;set;}
   public IEnumerable<string> Files {get;set;} // this is list of string
}
```

Below is the code which does that

```
IList<SourceBatch> list = GetSourceList();

var result = list.GroupBy(x => new
{
    ID = x.ID,
    BatchName = x.BatchName
})
.Select(y => new DestinationBatch()
{
     ID = y.Key.ID,
     BatchName = y.Key.BatchName,
     Files = y.Select(z => z.File)
 }).ToList();
```

This is working fine except in one case.
For `Batch1` where `File` is null, its populating `Files` property with one null record. I dont want to include null file into `Files`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add a `Where` clause. `Select` will always be run on every item in the `IEnumerable` and must return a value:

```
Files = y.Where( z => z.File != null).Select(s => s.File)
```

Answer (score 2):

Than write simple :

```
Files = y.Select(z => z.File).Where(z=>z!=null)
```

in your `Select` statement

or event better:

```
Files = y.Select(z => z.File).Where(z=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(z))
```

Comment: I would think the Where being first would be preferred

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Could be, i don't see large difference, but it sounds more logical, therefore you have my upvote, i havn't seen your solution as i posted mine .)

Comment: The only difference I could see is if `Select` was expensive, you would run it more times than necessary